Puedo poner un cursor en un boton en Kivy Python?
Tengo un programa que muestra un boton en una ventana, todo hecho con Kivy y me preguntaba si puedo agregarle un cursor distinto al boton cuando este sobre el boton. Lo intente pero me dio error.
Mi código del botón:
Button:
    text: "Inicio de Sección"
    on_press: root.pagina_progreso()            
    pos: 200, 590
    size_hint: None, None
    color:  (0.071, 0.416, 0.427)
    font_name: "MulledWineSeason.otf"               
    width: 150
    height: 40
    background_color: (212, 232, 232)
    cursor: pointer



¿Es distinta a tu pregunta anterior? Si es la misma pregunta, mejor editas la original para no tener dos preguntas iguales dando vuelta.

**Esta bien **

Supongo que te refieres a cambiar el puntero/cursor del ratón cuando éste esté posicionado encima del botón.
La propiedad cursor no existe en la clase Button, si en TextInput por ejemplo, pero en este caso lo que permite es posicionar el cursor.
Puedes establecer un cursor distinto mediente Window.set_system_cursor(), los valores permitidos son ‘arrow’, ‘ibeam’, ‘wait’, ‘crosshair’, ‘wait_arrow’, ‘size_nwse’, ‘size_nesw’, ‘size_we’, ‘size_ns’, ‘size_all’, ‘no’ y ‘hand’.
Un ejemplo muy simple usando "hand":
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window



kv = """
AnchorLayout:
    HandCursorButton:
        text: "Inicio de Sesión"
        size_hint: None, None
        color:  0.071, 0.416, 0.427
        size: 150, 40
        background_color: 212, 232, 232
"""


class HandCursorButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._is_mouseover = False
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouseover)

    def on_mouseover(self, _, pos):
        if self.collide_point(*pos):
            if not self._is_mouseover:
                self._is_mouseover = True
                Window.set_system_cursor('hand')
        elif self._is_mouseover:
            self._is_mouseover = False
            Window.set_system_cursor('arrow')


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()


Se pueden incluso renderizar cursores personalizados, pero es algo bastante más complejo.
